# EntityQuery to filter values returned based on List(text) field

Tags: 9

I have a List(text) field that can have multiple values. I am trying to create an entityQuery that returns nodes with specific items are checked within the field. The variable "availableServices" is an array of available services. I tried adding an andconditiongroup but that results in no items being returned. How do I check if a field has multiple values selected?

I've checked and when I search for items separately it returns values, but multiple items returns nothing. The nodes however have multiple items checked so it should return nodes.

```
if(isset($availableServices)) {
  $and = $query->andConditionGroup();
  foreach($availableServices as $service) {
    $and->condition('field_available_services', $service);
  }
  $query->condition($and);
}
```

----**Updated**---

Basically I need to convert this into an entityquery:

```
SELECT "node_field_data"."created" AS "node_field_data_created", "node_field_data"."nid" AS "nid"
FROM
{node_field_data} "node_field_data"
INNER JOIN {node__field_available_services} "node__field_available_services_value_0" ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_available_services_value_0.entity_id AND node__field_available_services_value_0.field_available_services_value = 'Deposit-taking ATM'
INNER JOIN {node__field_available_services} "node__field_available_services_value_1" ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_available_services_value_1.entity_id AND node__field_available_services_value_1.field_available_services_value = 'Check Cashing'
INNER JOIN {node__field_location_type} "node__field_location_type" ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_location_type.entity_id AND node__field_location_type.deleted = '0'
WHERE ((node__field_location_type.field_location_type_value IN('Branch', 'ATM', 'Branch & ATM'))) AND (("node_field_data"."status" = '1') AND ("node_field_data"."type" IN ('branch_location')) AND (("node__field_available_services_value_0"."field_available_services_value" = 'Deposit-taking ATM') AND ("node__field_available_services_value_1"."field_available_services_value" = 'Check Cashing')))
ORDER BY "node_field_data_created" DESC
```

Comment: Either `$availableServices` is a string or it is an array. You cannot compare an array to a string, nor pass a string to `foreach`.

Comment: @apaderno It's an array. That's what I said in the comment.

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done in one query. Did you try to set a base condition with "IN" condition and then loop through the results to keep only those that have all the specified available services?